# group and count by nested association in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

So I have the following associations (An Order comes from a Catch that is of a fish).

I want to, group a set of orders by the fish they are of, and then sum the quantity ordered attribute within order for each group.

I can do it for each catch with

Order.all.group(:catch_id).sum(:qty_ordered)

but not for the fish.

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :catch
end

class Catch < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :orders
    belongs_to :fish
end

class Fish < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :catches
end
```

Any tips?

Comment: Do you mean you want to do this: `Order.all.group(:fish_id).sum(:qty_ordered)` ?

Comment: I ended up getting it by doing `Order.joins(:catch).group(:fish_id).sum(:qty_ordered)`

Answer (score 1):

You are doing this: Order.all.group(:catch_id).sum(:qty_ordered)

and it works because Order has a field called `catch_id`, so you can group by that field.

If you want to group by `fish_id` you would have to have a column `fish_id` in Orders and Orders would have a `belongs_to :fish` association.

To group_by another related column it would be something like this:

```
Order.all.group_by {|order| order.catch.fish}
```

This is not the same `group` function, this is the Enumerable function `group_by`. Since your query returns an enumerable, it can be used. It will return a hash with each key being a Fish object, and the value being an array of Order objects that have that fish in them. This may not be the dataset you are looking for. Also you will not be able to just chain a `.sum` onto it.

You need to look at your model relations and either use a relation that exists to get the data you want, or create more associations to be able to pull the data you want. An example of the exact data set you want would help determine your needs.

An aside, using Order as a model may not be the best form. Rails has a method `.order` and you might find a conflict somewhere along the way.

Comment: I didn't want to use group_by because that's significantly slower than doing it within an ActiveRecord Query - I ended up solving it with ``Order.joins(:catch).group(:fish_id).sum(:qty_ordered)``

Comment: Of course, good call. I focused on what you were asking rather than even thinking of a join!

Comment: Yay, another down vote on an old answer. What douchenozzle does that? If someone would like to point out what is wrong with this answer I'd love to hear it. SMH